# Can magic be used to transform a muggle into a witch/wizard? (HP universe)

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

Could a very accomplished witch/wizard cast any number of spells or charms to give a muggle some amount of magical powers? Could it be even theoretically possible?

Comment: I imagine it would be similar to charming an inanimate object - over time the charm would wear off.

Comment: It seems unlikely; if it were possible, every [Squib](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Squib) would attempt to avail him/herself of it.  That being said, they *do* have some 'magical' characteristics, but your question is about muggles, not squibs.  A muggle being levitated would appear magic, but it would be coming from the casting wizard.  The same for transformations (Dudley's tail, for example.)  To clarify, I think you are asking if magic could be imbued into a muggle, causing them to forever after have some magical ability, like magnetizing a piece of steel.

Comment: not possible.because wizards are born, not made in hogwarts

Comment: Don't think it is possible do to the fact your born with the ability to perform magic, not made to perform magic.

Comment: Only if you have the lost book of [*Fuaran*](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39163/how-does-anton-outwit-kostya)

Comment: I believe it's possible in principle, such as with the "Imbue with Spell Ability" DnD spell http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/imbueWithSpellAbility.htm , but rarely happens in practice.  First, the existance of Wizards is generally kept a secret, and letting Muggles cast spells would go against this.  Secondly, the process is very inefficient: a wizard needs to cast a difficult spell to give powers to a Muggle, and even then the Muggle can cast only a very simple spell or use simple magic items.  It would be easier for the wizard to just accompany the Muggle and cast spells for them.

Comment: To all of the answers, we could add the caveat that if it is possible, the means to do so have not been discovered. Whether the power is absent or merely blocked is also still a matter of conjecture.

Comment: I would suspect that a retrovirus designed to inject the magical gene into the person's DNA could overtime (as the retrovirus works) give a muggle the ability to do magic. What a retrovirus does is it transcribes a copy of rna into dna and inserts it into the host cell's dna. A cleverly written retrovirus could hypothetically insert the DNA needed to make one magical and as it spreads through all the cells, it'll in essence change the person to be magical permanently.

Comment: The third Fantastic Beasts movie should address this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TL;DR version: **The magical gene is passed on from generation to generation; in purebloods it will always be passed on in full or as a Squib; if it is produced in a Squib, then that Squib's great-great-great x4 grandchildren will randomly get the magical gene. *As a result, even Muggleborns are distantly related to Purebloods.***

In the Deathly Hallows, it is **explicitly** stated that magic cannot be transferred or created within a person who was *born* without the magic 'gene', as it were:

> “But how are they supposed to have ‘stolen’ magic?” said Ron. “It’s mental, if you **could steal magic there wouldn’t be any Squibs, would there**?”
>
> “I know,” said Lupin. “Nevertheless, unless you can prove that
>   you have at least one close Wizarding relative, you are now deemed
>   to have obtained your magical power illegally and must suffer the
>   punishment.”
>
> **- Deathly Hallows, *The Bribe*, page 209 -**

Following the rules of genetic inheritance, we can ascertain that this is a likely sequence for the passing of the 'gene' for magic (please note, there is a minor error - Halfblood Traibortina is actually a Muggleborn):

[image: Gene Patterns]

- Where *pink* is a pureblood wizard (dominant magic gene, for example MM);
- Where *blue box with black text* is a Squib carrier (a mutated magical or Squib gene, for example Ss);
- Where *blue box with gray text* is a Squib/Muggle (a hidden mutated magical gene) and;
- Where *pink box with gray text* is a Muggleborn wizard (with a dominant mutated magical gene, producing SS and;
- Where *white box* is a half-blood wizard.

This doesn't line up perfectly (or at all, really) with genetic rules, but we can see that magic recedes and dominates over generations - much like blood types.

In this example, Sorceress and Wizard Traiborn both are purebloods, and produce two pureblood children, but owing to a mutation, produce a third squib child.

This squib has the magical gene, but it will surface randomly over many generations. The squib marries a Muggle, and they create a prospering Muggle dynasty.

Meanwhile, Wizard Traiborn Jr marries Sorceress Bobby, and as they are both purebloods, produce **only** pureblood children.

Several dozen generations pass.

Randomly and inexplicably, the magic gene "resurfaces" in Muggleborn Traibornet.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot :) This answer was pretty much perfect. Just one query though, the line "deemed to have obtained magical powers illegally" makes it sound like there _was_ a way to obtain magical powers illegally. Does this imply the existence of an actual way, or does it just imply the death-eater's ignorance towards the nature of magical inheritance?

Comment: @AshishKulkarni I'm not sure if you've read DH or not, but, (SPOILER ALERT) Voldemort takes over the Ministry of Magic and forces pureblood agendas through it. He commissioned a false report saying that Muggle-borns 'stole' magic - which is false, they always had a magic gene within them.

Comment: thanks, I have indeed read DH(albeit a couple of years back). I was just wondering as to whether Voldemort was just being plain ignorant and was using this "stole" thing as an excuse to prosecute Muggle-borns...

Comment: This is conjecture, but here goes: Wizards are like sheep. They believe anything that the Prophet or the Ministry says. It's ironic that for such an eccentric and individualistic society, they believe everything the Ministry says. **So yes, Voldemort did just make an excuse to persecute Muggleborns. He probably knew it was BS, like most despots.** But either way, I suspect that people like Umbridge would be fine even if he didn't give an excuse.

Answer (score 2):

No. In Book 7, Harry says that if people could steal magical powers, no one would be a squib. This is when talking about the Muggle born registry. Therefore, people cannot steal or obtain magical powers without being born with them.

Comment: Can you add the exact quote from the book?

Answer (score -2):

The later books make it clear that it's impossible, but I guess a Muggle/Squib could acquire temporary magic powers due to blood transfusion if you look at the first book, where it's said that the Muggles were so because of absence of magical blood in their veins.

Comment: I think that blood is just metaphorical.

Comment: May not be. I have read about other fictional settings where magical power was imparted using blood, but it faded slowly as the blood thinned.